# How to send a valid request to your own TFS server?

Tags: javascript, .net, plugins, get, tfs-2015

I'm trying to write a plugin for TFS **2015** (its important). I read a couple of manuals. the examples all turns out simply, but it is more difficult with a real plugin. my problem: i cant send any get/post request from my tfs server to same server. I always get the same response: 401 Unauthorized. I looked at examples that sending Ajax requests (https://github.com/ALM-Rangers/Work-Item-Details-Widget-Extension/blob/master/src/scripts/menu.js) and add auth token to request, but i get same error 401.
my code:

```
VSS.require(["VSS/Authentication/Services"], function(Services) {
    var authTokenManager = Services.authTokenManager;
    VSS.getAccessToken().then(function(token) {

        var header = authTokenManager.getAuthorizationHeader(token);
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: { 'Authorization': header }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://myTFSServ:8080/tfs/_api/_common/GetCollectionJumpList?__v=5&navigationContextPackage=%7B%22Action%22%3A%22index%22%2C%22Area%22%3A%22%22%2C%22Level%22%3A8%2C%22Controller%22%3A%22workItems%22%7D&selectedHostId=6e60eeec-39b3-4902-a864-172cd27dea91&api-version=3.0-preview.2",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(c) {
                debugger;
                // do something...;
            },
            error: function(e) {
                debugger;
                var error = e;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

how can i send any valid get/post request from my tfs server to same server??

Comment: Do you mean it is working fine when send the request from different machine? Try to disable the loopback check (https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/896861/you-receive-error-401.1-when-you-browse-a-web-site-that-uses-integrated-authentication-and-is-hosted-on-iis-5.1-or-a-later-version)

Comment: No, I mean I'm trying to send a request from my machine (on which the TFS server installed) to the same server

Comment: What's the result if you send the request manually?

Comment: did you find the solution?